# Generating HMAC message digest via Crypto class

Tags: apex, crypto, encryption

I have an API Integration which expects a HMAC-SHA256 signature. Example:

```
message = 'testmessage'
secret key = '123456789'
signature: 9cba4d1d75689509208a97b1ca42f786a630a891e2410bfb11a84feb7a4807ad
```

How can I generate the same signature in Apex? I tried the `generateMac` function from the `Crypto` class but it gives a different value than the one expected. Below is the code:

```
Blob blobSignature = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('testmessage'), Blob.valueOf('123456789'));
System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blobSignature));
```

**Output: nLpNHXVolQkgipexykL3hqYwqJHiQQv7EahP63pIB60=**

What I am doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are encoding it wrong. Try below code:

```
Blob blobSignature = Crypto.generateMac('hmacSHA256', Blob.valueOf('testmessage'), Blob.valueOf('123456789'));
System.debug(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobSignature));
```

output

```
17:42:10:023 USER_DEBUG [56]|DEBUG|9cba4d1d75689509208a97b1ca42f786a630a891e2410bfb11a84feb7a4807ad
```