# Trustpilot encryption process

Tags: apex, encryption

I am working on the Encryption process.

I need to generate encrypted payload by following instructions from the below link:
   https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004145087--Business-Generated-Links-for-developers-

I tried below code below:

```
String text = '{\"email\":\"sudharani256@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sudha Rani\",\"ref\":\"1234\"}';
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(text);
Blob iv =Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
BLob encryptKeyDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('.............');
BLob authKeyDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('............');
Blob cipherText = Crypto.encrypt('AES256', encryptKeyDecode, iv,data);


String ivCipherString = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(iv)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText);

Blob ct = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(ivCipherString);




String algorithmName = 'hmacSHA256';
Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName,ct,authKeyDecode);

String base64_payload  = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(iv)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText)+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
String urlEncodeInfohmacData = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData),'UTF-8');

system.debug(urlEncodeInfohmacData);

String urlEncodeInfo = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(base64_payload,'UTF-8');

system.debug(urlEncodeInfo);
```

Please help me it is very needful.

Comment: TrustPilot instructions don't mention a RSA signature. Why would you try that?

Comment: In 3rd step, it is asking like  "Create a signature of the ciphertext". So, in that process, I am trying to create a signature with the help of Crypto.sign. There I tried different algorithms like RSA-SHA256 and RSA.

Comment: Do you know how to create a signature of the ciphertext?
Do you know what to mention for privatekey/crypto key(sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey)
)?

Comment: Here is the sample python code, they are not generating any crypto key. They are just using the encryption key and Auth key.

https://github.com/trustpilot/python-authenticated-encryption

Comment: Take a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66138/generating-hmac-message-digest-via-crypto-class

Comment: Thank you if you observe,  I used generateMac only but I used base64Encode instead of EncodingUtil.convertToHex to encode in the string formate. Just before I tried EncodingUtil.convertToHex as well but it is not working(not throwing error but not giving correct encrypted output).

Comment: You have most of it right. If you want this forum to help you, you'll need to post  a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and the code or metadata to reproduce the problem. Please limit code inclusions to only the relevant elements, such as an MVR (minimum viable reproduction). Please edit your question instead of using comments.

Comment: the encryption key and auth key are confidential(client's credentials not my personal credentials). I am facing no error except ""System.SecurityException: Invalid Crypto Key" and moreover even if I use EncodingUtil.generateMac(), generated one is not a proper one. Somewhere I am missing.

Comment: You can create your own keys for a minimum viable reproduction. You're not going to get help here unless you adhere to the rules.

Comment: I created a sample account, but it is asking me to upgrade, which is expecting payment. Still, I clicked on upgrade, showed a message as we will contact you.
They did not contact me back until this time. I clicked on the upgrade four days back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cracked it.

String text = '{\"email\":\"sudharani256@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sudha Rani\",\"ref\":\"1234\"}';
Blob encryptCode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('...........');
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(text);

Blob ciphertextAndIV = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', encryptCode, data);

BLob authKeyDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('.............................');

String ciphertextAndIVTExt = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(ciphertextAndIV);
String algorithmName = 'hmacSHA256';
Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName,ciphertextAndIV,authKeyDecode);

String base64_payload  = ciphertextAndIVTExt+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData);
String urlEncodeInfohmacData = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(base64_payload,'UTF-8');

system.debug(urlEncodeInfohmacData);

Comment: But this solution is not giving proper output for lengthy payload.

Answer (score 0):

try by concatenating blob using EncodingUtil.convertToHex():
[How to combine multiple Blob in apex to get single Blob value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133380/how-to-combine-multiple-blob-in-apex-to-get-single-blob-value)

```
String text = '{\"email\":\"sudharani256@gmail.com\",\"name\":\"Sudha Rani\",\"ref\":\"1234\"}';
Blob data = Blob.valueOf(text);
Blob iv =Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
BLob encryptKeyDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('.............');
BLob authKeyDecode = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('............');
Blob cipherText = Crypto.encrypt('AES256', encryptKeyDecode, iv,data);


String ivCipherString =EncodingUtil.convertToHex(iv)+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(cipherText);

Blob ct =  EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(ivCipherString);




String algorithmName = 'hmacSHA256';
Blob hmacData = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName,ct,authKeyDecode);


String base64_payload  = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(EncodingUtil.convertToHex(iv)+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(cipherText)+EncodingUtil.convertToHex(hmacData)));
String urlEncodeInfohmacData = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hmacData),'UTF-8');

system.debug(urlEncodeInfohmacData);

String urlEncodeInfo = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(base64_payload,'UTF-8');

system.debug(urlEncodeInfo);
```