# How Verify HMAC in Salesforce

Tags: apex, crypto

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
Data = '1605470404trashed';
Private Key = '5034eafbf7068b76e4762db248effd77';
Algoithm: SHA256
```

Actual HMAC generated from service = e4911d1d188c24d313a159d38f1beb06e56c53f87ae0833820aef7c3a3812b96

When I use this service I get the correct HMAC:

https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html

When I use this code in salesforce to verify it returns false:

```
Crypto.verifyHmac(
        'hmacSHA256',
        blob.valueOf('1605470404trashed'),
        blob.valueOf('5034eafbf7068b76e4762db248effd77'),
        blob.valueOf('e4911d1d188c24d313a159d38f1beb06e56c53f87ae0833820aef7c3a3812b96')
);
```

And when I try to generate the same HMAC I get a value that is nowhere near the result expected:

```
Blob bdata = Blob.valueOf('1605470404trashed');
Blob encrypted = Crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA256',bdata, blob.valueOf('5034eafbf7068b76e4762db248effd77'));
System.debug( EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encrypted));
```

returns: X4u/2/COJQR1yxUmDcxIp5BxcgYxLz+0X08FB4Bg5Oc=

Any ideas how to verify the HMAC e4911d1d188c24d313a159d38f1beb06e56c53f87ae0833820aef7c3a3812b96 in salesforce using the above information?

Part about generating HMAC is answered by
[Generating HMAC message digest via Crypto class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66138/generating-hmac-message-digest-via-crypto-class)

Still curious why `verifyHMAC` returns false. Maybe it cannot be used for this use case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating HMAC message digest via Crypto class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66138/generating-hmac-message-digest-via-crypto-class) It appears instead of base64Encode it should be convertToHex.

Comment: @tugce - It does answer the part about generating. thank you. But it still does not work with the verifyHMAC. I know I could generate it then just do a straight compare but would be interested in if the provided verifyHMAC method could be used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `Blob.valueOf(hmacString)` you need to use `EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(hmacString)` to generate the blob for the HMAC part.

```
Boolean verified = Crypto.verifyHmac(
        'hmacSHA256',
        blob.valueOf('1605470404trashed'),
        blob.valueOf('5034eafbf7068b76e4762db248effd77'),
        encodingutil.convertFromHex('e4911d1d188c24d313a159d38f1beb06e56c53f87ae0833820aef7c3a3812b96')
);
system.debug(verified); //22:22:16:010 USER_DEBUG [10]|DEBUG|true
```

Comment: ConvertFromHex it was. Thanks